# Loading PNG file. Need to get RGBA HBITMAP

Tags: c++, png, transparency, gdi+

I'm trying to create a splash screen that will show transparent png background. So at first I need to load png file into format that is acceptable for the UpdateLayeredWindow calls (basically HBITMAP with RGBA format).

At the moment, I've found *Windows Imaging Component*, but that does not work for VS2005 (which is mandatory requirement). Using some additional libraries is also a problem.

I've heard that GDI+ can do the trick, but I can't find a proper example unfortunately :( Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are having. The loading of the file from disk? or are you having problems working with the image once loaded from memory? Also could you supply some code in which you use the image in question?

Comment: Ok, I could not understand how to get HBITMAP handle (in RGBA format) from a PNG file using GDI+. I was worried that plain Image::FromFile would not support alpha channel. As it turned out, it is a pretty easy task:

HBITMAP hBitmap;
Bitmap m_pImage = Bitmap::FromFile(L"TransparentPNG.png", FALSE);  
Gdiplus::Color bg(0,0,0,0);  
m_pImage->GetHBITMAP(bg, &hBitmap);

Comment: ok that makes more sense. I am glad you figured it out.

Comment: Somehow I have trouble inserting properly formatted code :( Need to go to sleep. Thanks to all who read the question